# Airflow connection pool keeping database busy with commits

Tags: database, postgresql, airflow

I am using airflow local executor with connection pool size 10, looks like airflow is continuously doing commits to database to keep connection alive after few milliseconds which is creating too many logs and keep database and network too chatty.

Logs snippet, can i do something to avoid that many logs in log file and less chatty network ?

```
2023-12-04 00:00:00.004 GMT [3007968]: [27-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOG:  00000: duration: 1.389 ms
2023-12-04 00:00:00.004 GMT [3007968]: [28-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOCATION:  exec_simple_query, postgres.c:1305
2023-12-04 00:00:00.023 GMT [3007965]: [31-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOG:  00000: duration: 2.191 ms
2023-12-04 00:00:00.023 GMT [3007965]: [32-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOCATION:  exec_simple_query, postgres.c:1305
2023-12-04 00:00:00.024 GMT [3007968]: [29-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOG:  00000: duration: 0.479 ms
2023-12-04 00:00:00.024 GMT [3007968]: [30-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOCATION:  exec_simple_query, postgres.c:1305
2023-12-04 00:00:00.060 GMT [3007968]: [31-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOG:  00000: duration: 1.852 ms
2023-12-04 00:00:00.060 GMT [3007968]: [32-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOCATION:  exec_simple_query, postgres.c:1305
2023-12-04 00:00:00.074 GMT [3007965]: [33-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOG:  00000: duration: 1.890 ms
2023-12-04 00:00:00.074 GMT [3007965]: [34-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOCATION:  exec_simple_query, postgres.c:1305
2023-12-04 00:00:00.095 GMT [3007965]: [35-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOG:  00000: duration: 0.678 ms
2023-12-04 00:00:00.095 GMT [3007965]: [36-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOCATION:  exec_simple_query, postgres.c:1305
2023-12-04 00:00:00.100 GMT [3007968]: [33-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOG:  00000: duration: 2.464 ms
2023-12-04 00:00:00.100 GMT [3007968]: [34-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOCATION:  exec_simple_query, postgres.c:1305
2023-12-04 00:00:00.116 GMT [3007965]: [37-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOG:  00000: duration: 0.618 ms
2023-12-04 00:00:00.116 GMT [3007965]: [38-1]db=airflow_db,user=airflow_user,app=[unknown],client=10.1.1.2LOCATION:  exec_simple_query, postgres.c:1305
```

If you see there are tons of database logs for just few miliseconds.